# Using method reference to call static methods

Tags: java, methods, reference, static

I am trying to understand the concept of Method references.
When trying out different calls, I stumbled upon a scenario which I cant fully understand.

When `canClim` is used without a parameter, it can be passed to `forEach` without problems although `forEach` takes a Consumer which should take in a parameter? When adding a parameter to `canClim` it prevents compiling?

However when `canClim` is declared as static it won't compile without adding static void `canClim(Animal a)` to the signature.
Shouldn't it be possible to call the static method without having a instance of the Animal class because it is static ?

Thanks!

```
import java.util.*;

class Animal {
    void canClim() {
        System.out.println("I am a climber!");
    }
}

public class MethodReferencer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal a = new Animal();
        Animal b = new Animal();
        List<Animal> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(a, b));
        list.forEach(Animal::canClim);

    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Comment: You really need to read on how method references are resolved. It would be too broad to answer here.

Comment: You can think of an instance method `Animal.canClim()` as a function which takes an Animal (this) as argument: `canClim(Animal this)`. When you think of it that way, it becomes obvious that this is a valid Consumer<Animal>. Static methods, on the other hand, have no `this`.

Comment: @JBNizet that makes sense, so the `this` is supplied to the accept of the consumer?

Comment: You got it right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the method is non-static,

`Animal::canClim`
is equivalent to
`animal -> animal.canClim()`
or
`(animal) -> animal.canClim()`

The `animal` on the left side of the lambda is the consumer function parameter, and the body is on the right. So yes, you *are* supplying a consumer there.

Static methods behaves a bit differently.
For example, `Integer::parseInt` would become `str -> Integer.parseInt(str)`.
 Basically the parameter is supplied to the parameter of the method. So in static methods, you need to have a parameter to be able to use method references.

Answer (score 0):

The `Consumer` has a method `accept` that takes an argument. A static method with no argument couldn't be converted to a `Consumer`, could it?